# Compute vector layer area with python in qgis

Tags: qgis, python, area

I need to identify in QGIS the area of a **Qgsvectorlayer** .

Anyone have an idea how to do that in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Polygon vectorlayer is composed of many features (geometries), each with an area.

If the geometries don't overlap, you can iterate over the vector layer and sum the areas:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
areatot = 0
for elem in layer.getFeatures()
     geom = elem.geometry()
     areatot += geom.area()
```

or in one line:

```
aeratot = [sum(elem.geometry().area() for elem in layer.getFeatures())]
```

But if some geometries overlap, this result is wrong:

[image]

You can then Union all the geometries and use the area of the resulting geometry:

[image]

```
# creation of a empty geometry for unioning
geomtot = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
# union
for elem in layer.getFeatures():
   geomtot = geomtot.combine(elem.geometry())
area = geomtot.area()
```

### For QGIS 1.8:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
areatot = 0
layer.select()
for elem in layer:
     geom = elem.geometry()
     areatot += geom.area()
```

and:

```
geomtot = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
layer.select()
for elem in layer:
    geomtot = geomtot.combine(elem.geometry())
area = geomtot.area()
```

Comment: yes this is what i am looking for

Comment: oh the function getFeatures() does'nt work in qgis 1.8

Comment: Then use `layer.select()` and `for feature in layer:`

Comment: see for 1.8 version in the answer

Answer (score 1):

In Qgis, go to plugins > Python console

Declare your layer

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("/path/to/shapefile/file.shp", "layer_name_you_like", "ogr")
```

and to get extent, do

```
vlayer.extent().toString()
```

`vlayer.extent()` return a qgis.core.QgsRectangle, so if you want, you can use different methods depending of you use case (see the doc for this component at http://qgis.org/api/2.0/classQgsRectangle.html)

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: No I cannot use the extent of layer ,i want to identify sum of features,the answer of gene look useful for me but its work on qgis api 2 ,thank you for your answer ThomasG77